# No Linkbutton for sorting at top of asp:GridView columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview

According to the GridView documentation on MSDN, setting AllowPaging = true on an ASP.NET GridView control automatically creates a LinkButton control at the top of every column, but I am just getting static text on this very simple bit of code.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdAttachments" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="pKey"
    OnSorting="grdAttachments_Sorting" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="AttchDate" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Name" DataField="AttchPath" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Attached By" DataField="AttchBy" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: When you say `AllowPaging = true` does it mean `AllowSorting="true"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no `SortExpression` property on your BoundField controls.. you should change it to:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="AttchDate" SortExpression="AttchDate" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Name" DataField="AttchPath" SortExpression="AttchPath" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Attached By" DataField="AttchBy" SortExpression="AttchBy" />
</Columns>
```

now you will see the link buttons in the column header.

Comment: YES!  Makes sense now that I think about it.  Beautiful!  Thank you sir.